# Spring Data Rest Jpa insert @Lob field

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a spring data rest service, that expose a resource like:

```
@Entity
public class Resource{
    private String name;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    private String contentType;
}
```

How should be a json to insert a resource of this type?

Comment: Try serializing to Json in your unit test to see how that looks or if you can get it working.

Comment: mmm it seems a base64 string...I will try.. thx

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, SDR does not handle multipart requests or responses yet, as it can only do JSON.

You can run SDR at the same time as a regular Spring MVC servlet (it's one line of code in your config).

I would suggest using a regular Spring MVC controller for your file upload/download, and SDR for the rest (pun intended).

Comment: Where can I read more about the Spring MVC servlet you're talking about?

Comment: @rascio you would setup a normal spring mvc servlet (see mkyong.com), and then add <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/> to your spring-mvc-servlet.xml config

Comment: Ah...I thought it was a different stuff ahah

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JSON.
"name" and "contentType" are part of the http header (respectively "Content-Type" and "Content-Disposition: filename")
"data" is the HTTP body. Its encoding depends of "Content-Encoding"
Maybe you should use "ResourceResolvers" plugged with JPA.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html) was designed for exactly this.

Assuming you are using Spring Boot then you can add LOB handling as follows:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

> Add a Store:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @StoreRestResource(path="resourceContent")
    public interface ResourceContentStore extends ContentStore<Resource,String> {}
}
```

> Associate content with your entity entity:

```
@Entity
public class Resource {

  private String name;

  @ContentId
  private String contentId;

  @ContentLength 
  private long contentLength = 0L;

  @MimeType
  private String mimeType = "text/plain";
}
```

That's all that you should need.  When you application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Spring Content JPA/REST modules and it will inject an implementation of the `ResourceContentStore` store for JPA as well as an implementation of a controller (at `/resourceContent`) that supports that maps GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests onto the underlying Store interface.  The REST endpoint will be available under.

i.e.

`curl -X PUT /resourceContent/{resourceId}` will create or update an resource's content

`curl -X GET /resourceContent/{resourceId}` will fetch the resource's content

`curl -X DELETE /resourceContent/{resourceId}` will delete the resources content

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the Filesystem but the modules are interchangeable.  The JPA reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/jpa-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).

HTH